# Bash: How to recursively ftp a certain file type under multiple directories

Tags: bash, recursion, ftp, wget, glob

Is it possible to have two wildcards? If not, is there another way of going about this problem?

I am trying to recursively get a file type from an ftp server using Bash. But, what I am having trouble with is that I am trying to remove files from multiple directories. Many of these directory names will have matching strings. The client will look for all directories with the matching string and get a certain file type from each. Each directory can have many files with the same extension.

What I have tried to do is use wget recursively.

```
wget -r 'ftp://anonymous:@$HOST/$PATH/$DIRSTRING*/*.$FILEEXT
```

This gives me an error message saying the $PATH/$DIRSTRING*/ file or directory could not be found.

I know wget supports globbing. But, is it possible to have two wildcards? If not, is there another way of going about this problem?

Best Regards

Comment: I think `$PATH/$DIRSTRING` should be expanded locally? You should try with double quotes as in `wget -r "ftp://..`

Comment: I got the same problem, using double quotes doesn't work, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

wget is not really suited for this kind of ftp usage...but lftp is very good at mirroring ftp site data, it even supports globbing! :)
for your example:

```
lftp -e "mirror -I '$DIRSTRING*/*$FILEEXT' /$RPATH mirrorSite" ftp://anonymous@$HOST
```

see `man lftp` / mirror command